# How to instantiate a class x times with different reference names?

Tags: java, object

i'm coding a program in java that should take some inputs from the user. I'm doing a GUI using swing. The program starts by opening a window in which the user types a string. Then the program decides how many alphabetic characters (abc...z) there is in the string. When the user presses enter, a new window pops up. This window has a bunch of options for each character there was in the first string. The problem arises when i want to create these options (in form of two JTextFields and one JTextBox per character in the first string). Each of these components are (of course) an object, but how do i instantiate a class x times and keep the ability to reference the objects its variables (or in this case the text of each JTextField).

As i have understood it from reading online, whenever i instantiate a class with something like this: `object Example = new object()` 
twice, and the first object i created osn't referenced anymore, there is no way i can retrieve anything from it, or do anything to it, which result in it being marked as unreferenced and eligible for garbage collection.

If anyone want to see what i tried to do, but then realized i could no longer reference the objects, which reference names was redefined, here is the loop that instantiated the classes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < VariableAmount; i++) {
        JLabel VariableLabel = new JLabel(VariableList.get(i) + "     =");
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, VariableLabel, 30 * i + 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, VariableLabel, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, frame.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, VariableLabel, 50, SpringLayout.WEST, frame.getContentPane());
        frame.getContentPane().add(VariableLabel);

        JCheckBox isInterval = new JCheckBox("Interval");
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, isInterval, 30 * i + 7, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, isInterval, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, isInterval, -80, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
        frame.getContentPane().add(isInterval);

        VariableValue = new JTextField();
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, VariableValue, 30 * i + 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, VariableValue, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, VariableLabel);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, VariableValue, -250, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
        frame.getContentPane().add(VariableValue);
        VariableValue.setColumns(10);

        VariablePlusMinus = new JTextField();
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, VariableValue, 30 * i + 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, VariableValue, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, VariableValue);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, VariableValue, -90, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
        frame.getContentPane().add(VariableValue);
        VariableValue.setColumns(10);
    }
```

So to see this in a more general perspective, what i need help to is to instantiate a class x times, with different reference names (not quite sure if this is possible).

I know this became a bit broad and i am sorry about that, but this is something i have needed quite some times in the past. Sry for my english and my code (new to programming).

Comment: Put them in a `List` or array and access by index, or a `Map` and access by a key.

Comment: @d.j.brown ty, i have done this with strings (which when i think about it, is an object) before. Don't know why i didn't think of this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use ArrayList. Inside the loop you can add each object to the respective List. By the time you exit the loop all the objects created in each iteration will be added into the list. Whenever you want to access individual object you can use list iterator.

```
ArrayList<JLabel> VariableLabelList =new ArrayList<JLable>();
ArrayList<JCheckBox> isIntervalList =new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
ArrayList<JTextField> VariableValueList =new ArrayList<JTextField>();
ArrayList<JTextField> VariablePlusMinusList =new ArrayList<JTextField>();
for(int i = 0; i < VariableAmount; i++) {
                    JLabel VariableLabel = new JLabel(VariableList.get(i) + "     =");
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, VariableLabel, 30 * i + 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, VariableLabel, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, frame.getContentPane());
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, VariableLabel, 50, SpringLayout.WEST, frame.getContentPane());
                    frame.getContentPane().add(VariableLabel);
                    VariableLabelList.add(VariableLabel);

                    JCheckBox isInterval = new JCheckBox("Interval");
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, isInterval, 30 * i + 7, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, isInterval, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, isInterval, -80, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
                    frame.getContentPane().add(isInterval);
                    isIntervalList.add(isInterval);

                    VariableValue = new JTextField();
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, VariableValue, 30 * i + 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, VariableValue, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, VariableLabel);
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, VariableValue, -250, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
                    frame.getContentPane().add(VariableValue);
                    VariableValue.setColumns(10);
                    VariableValueList.add(VariableValue);

                    VariablePlusMinus = new JTextField();
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, VariableValue, 30 * i + 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, VariableValue, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, VariableValue);
                    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, VariableValue, -90, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
                    frame.getContentPane().add(VariableValue);
                    VariableValue.setColumns(10);
                    VariablePlusMinusList.add(VariablePlusMinus);
}
```